# How can I to display an amount in UK format?

Tags: angular6

I am using angular 6. I want to display a number value in comma separated amount.

i.e amount 123456 or 7456 as 123,456 and 7,456 in angular using pipe or other better way?

I think i made it work. i used {{ val | number}}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
{{val | number}}
```

The above converts as expected. eg.
123456 or 7456 as 123,456 and 7,456